# How to prevent access to specific routes in Symfony 2

Tags: security, symfony, routes, yaml

I'm new to symfony2 and I don't understand the way the security.yml works

I have 2 roles in my application: ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN.

ROLE_USER: can only view (cannot CRUD)
ROLE_ADMIN: can do everything (can CRUD)

I have 2 basic questions:

1. Is there only 1 security.yml in app/config? Can I create a security.yml for my bundle ThePartner\EZFBundle\Resource\config where I can specify which route a role can access?
2. I want to prevent ROLE_USER to access to route blue_form_new, blue_form_create, blue_form_edit, blue_form_update, blue_form_delete? This ROLE_USER could only access blue_form, blue_form_show

Here is my ThePartner\EZFBundle\Resources\routing.yml

```
ThePartnerEZFBundle_blue_form:
    resource: "@ThePartnerEZFBundle/Resources/config/routing/blueform.yml"
    prefix:   /blue_form
```

Here is the ThePartnerEZFBundle/Resources/config/routing/blueform.yml

```
blue_form:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:index" }

blue_form_show:
    pattern:  /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:show" }

blue_form_new:
    pattern:  /new
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:new" }

blue_form_create:
    pattern:  /create
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:create" }
    requirements: { _method: post }

blue_form_edit:
    pattern:  /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:edit" }

blue_form_update:
    pattern:  /{id}/update
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:update" }
    requirements: { _method: post|put }

blue_form_delete:
    pattern:  /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "ThePartnerEZFBundle:BlueForm:delete" }
    requirements: { _method: post|delete }
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to configure is your `security.yml`. You can define multiple firewalls which will apply to different routes:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        your_first_firewall:
            pattern: /public/ #this is regexp, so all urls starting with /public/ will   match
            security: false #this will be public, no firewall
        your_second_firewall:
            pattern: /nonPublic/
            security: true
```

Remember that order of your firewall entries is important - first pattern matched will "win".

You can also import security settings from your bundle. To do that you need to import your bundle's `security.yml` file in main `config.yml` - described [here](http://robertbasic.com/blog/importing-symfony2-security-settings-from-a-bundle))

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/security.yml' }
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! I follow the link to import an empty security.yml. But there was an error saying Cannot import resource "@ThePartnerEZFBundle/Resources/config/security.xml" from "/Users/anhnch/Documents/working/easyform/src/app/config/config.yml". Make sure the "ThePartnerEZFBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. Although that I did register the bundle in the AppKernel correctly (it was generated by the commandline)

Comment: is it because the importing happens before the bundle registration?

Comment: no, order has nothing to do here. Are you sure the file exists (with xml extension)? It's either file does not exists or bundle is not loaded correctly (or the name doesn't fit) - no other options

Comment: My fault, I mistakenly imported the security.xml instead of security.yml. Thank you very much Tomasz :)